# Can someone help me fix my roblox Lua scripting?

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

I made a zombie script with waves but then I got an error called "attempted to index nil with humanoid" so when I load it in my game I type in /console and the error keeps popping up, at first I thought my game had a virus but I fixed them all and there's still this error can someone help me even my friend can't help me. Thanks!

I have tried using various tools, asked my friends and also hired a Roblox Scripter for $1, but they couldn't fix it.

Here's my script for reference:

```
local spawns = script.Parent

local spawn_time = 10

while true do
    wait(spawn_time)
    for _,spwn in pairs(spawns:GetChildren()) do
        if spwn:IsA('BasePart') then 
            local zombieCopy = game.ReplicatedStorage['Drooling Zombie']:Clone()
            zombieCopy.Parent.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = CFrame.new(spwn.Postiion + Vector3.new(0,3,0))

        end
    end
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

For those asking for what my idea is heres youtube link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=klHXlim9Yuw

Comment: Are you sure this is the script that is throwing errors? The error you are getting is saying that you are trying to access`Humanoid` on an object that doesn't exist, but you weren't accessing the Humanoid at all in this Script. Could you double check the error message and the script because I don't think this is the right code.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you are attempting to spawn a zombie model on the player when they spawn? Could you please also clarify where your script is, and what error you receive when you play the game and run the script? If anything is wrong in my response, please modify it accordingly or comment on what I have done wrong considering I haven't tested this script yet. From the script you have provided me, here's a somewhat better version of your script:

```
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")

local spawn = script.Parent
local duration = 10

local function summonZombie()
   for _, spawn in pairs(spawn:GetChildren()) do
      local zombieCopy = ReplicatedStorage['Drooling Zombie']:Clone()
      zombieCopy.Parent.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = CFrame.new(spawn.Position + Vector3.new(0,3,0))
   end
end

while true do task.wait(duration) summonZombie() end
```

May I mention, there is a typo on the zombieCopy line, so that's something to point out. Please ensure you check your script for any silly mistakes like that before posting to SO.

One last thing, **never use `game.[Service]` for calling in-game services like `Workspace` or `Players`. Instead use:**

```
local Workspace = game:GetService("Workspace")
```

... not:

```
local Workspace = game.Workspace
```

Edit: sorry, I forgot to close the `for` statement.
I have updated the code above accordingly, thanks for the report.

Comment: thanks men and also i got an error its this now the error is gone but im experiencing another error called" workspace.spawn.script:13: Expected 'end' (to close function at line 7), got <eof>; did you forget to close 'do' at line 8?" also thanks again for the script because its actually a game im gonna make for my brothers birthday because he wants to become famous XD. but tbh i dont think that will happen but i rea;;y need your help so thank you bro and belated new year

its Smulsqueen gaming,(Your personal gamer XD)
Signing off.

Comment: Smulsqueen could you please mark my answer correct if it helped you - and I also modified my answer accordingly to the error.